# scanner.java tab appears when I try to use debugger

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

When I try to use the debugger (<kbd>F7</kbd>) in NetBeans, it does not seem to work properly for me. While normally it would move step by step through the program, my debugger instead opens a new tab called "scanner.java" the second time I press <kbd>F7</kbd>. If someone could help me with this issue, that'd be great!

Comment: Isn't that because the line that you are trying to debug requires the user to input some values? Hence, scanner.java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/shortcuts-80.pdf) (see [all shortcuts here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Keyboard_Shortcuts))

- <kbd>F7</kbd> is for stepping into
- <kbd>F8</kbd> is for stepping over

So, it is behaving correctly. When you step into some code the debugger moves into that calls stack.

If you want to "move step by step through the program" you need to press **<kbd>F8</kbd>**

**Further readings**

- Oracle documentation: Running and Debugging Java Application Projects, [Table 9-3 Debugging Step Commands and Icons](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/run_debug_japps.htm#BABHCFCG)